# How to filter results of an Azure Devops REST API GET request

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to collect some metrics on releases in Azure Devops via a Powershell script.

I have very limited dev experience and am new to PowerShell.  And this is the first time I have worked with an API.  So far I have been able to authenticate, return a list of releases, loop through them and export the data to a file. Now I need to filter the releases based on a substring of the release name.  For the record I have been doing my initial testing in Postman to make sure my syntax and results are correct.  Then I migrated working syntax to Powershell.

`https://{{organization}}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{{project}}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0`

If I add the id filter as shown here:
`https://{{organization}}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{{project}}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0&releaseId=34567`

I get this result:

`"id": 34567,
"name": "Test-Release-MyService",`

But if use the same filter format for Release Name,
`https://{{organization}}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{{project}}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0&releaseName="Test-Release-MyService"`

I get back 50 results of which none match that criteria, whether I wrap the string in quotes or not.  Furthermore, what i really want to do is to have the response only include records where the releaseName contains "XYZ".

So the question: Is there a filter operator  for **"contains"** so I only get back records where the release name contains the "XYZ" substring?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: I don't have any way to test this, but I'm guessing the correct parameter to use would be "searchText". Refer to the API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#uri-parameters

I don't even see "releaseName" as a valid parameter.

Comment: Ah, I just assumed that if it was one of values in the returned data,  i could filter on it.  But your comment makes sense, that if it is not one of the URI parameters, you cannot filter on it.  And now that seems so obvious, I am embarrassed.    So since I cannot filter on the name, do I have to evaluate each record as it is coming in?

Comment: No problem, easy mistake to make! And it looks like the description for searchText says: "Releases with names containing searchText." It seems like you can use that to filter by name?

Comment: So that seems like the direction I need to go. But when I use it, I still get back 50 non-matching results. Am I still missing something? 
```https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/release/releases?searchText =298&api-version=5.0```

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if intentional or not, but there's a space after searchText? Otherwise without having access to the API I'm not sure what else you can try. Maybe since this is specifically relating to the API you can try posting in Microsoft forums?

Comment: Not intentional.  And yes, that resolves it.  Thank you for assisting with a newbie.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: @kuzimoto, can you distill this into an answer?

Comment: Is there a NOT contains?

Answer (score 1):

Every parameter you used in Azure DevOps REST API needs to be consistent with the description in the document, Azure DevOps REST API does not support custom parameters. For your question, the parameter `searchText` is used to filter the the searching result with the release name containing the keyword. I have tested with POSTMAN to call the api, it works fine. In addition, the value of parameter `searchText` is not case-sensitive. [Filter release name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQxVS.png)

If you want to do more filter, in fact you can use powershell or other client library to deserialize the json response to an object, and do some convert or filter. Following documents may be helpful for you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/playing-with-json-and-powershell/